# Cannot redirect with forwardauth Traefik middleware

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, traefik

How to actually switch(redirect) to another server having login page with Traefik ForwardAuth ?
I'm using the following docker labels:

```
'traefik.http.routers.my-route.rule=Host("main.int")'
'traefik.http.routers.my-route.entrypoints=https443'
'traefik.http.routers.my-route.tls=true'
'traefik.http.routers.my-route.middlewares=my-test-auth@docker
'traefik.http.middlewares.my-test-auth.forwardauth.address=https://auth.page.int/login/'
'traefik.http.middlewares.my-test-auth.forwardauth.tls.insecureSkipVerify=true'
```

Traefik logs shows that is accessing the `auth.page.int/login` page:

`GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/2.0" 200 3459`
but browser stays on the main page.

BTW redirect works with `RedirectRegex` middleware for the same example.

Documentation: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/overview/